# Can a variable named as `$something` be referred to by `someting`, that is without the dollar sign?

Tags: php, variable-names

I am examining some PHP code written by somebody else, and they have basically named a variable `$text`:

```
protected $text = null;
```

And then later in the same file, they are referring to it without the `$` sign:

```
$this->text[$name] = new Text($age, $house);
```

1. I am a little intrigued. Is this even possible? Can a variable named
   with a `$` concatenated with some word, be referred with only the
   part of the identifier other than `$`?
2. If yes, does it imply something special or is it a simple reference
   to the variable?

PS: I don't think the code is faulty because it works =s

Comment: `$text` is not a variable, it's a class property. Properties are accessed using `$var->propertyname`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, but does this mean we always have to access them without the `$`, or it can either be `$var->propertyname` or `$var->$propertyname`?

Comment: `$var->$propertyname means to use the value of `$propertyname` as the name of the property, e.g. `$propertyname = "text"; $this->$propertyname = "foo";` is equivalent to `$this->text = "foo";`. Please read the section of the PHP manual on OO programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not faulty it's because it is writen in Object Oriented PHP.
When you declare an attribute in a php object, in that case `$text`, you can later in that same class refer to that attribute as `$this->text`.

Answer (score 1):

That is how you access a variable (often called a *property*) in object oriented code.

```
class MyClass {
    public $name = 'Billy Bob';
    public function printName() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
```

In this example `$this->name` refers to the `$name` variable, belonging to "this" instance of the class (an instance of a class is called an *object*).

```
class MyClass { /* ... */ } // This is a class definition
$obj = new MyClass();       // This is an instance of the class, an object
```